Sum of odd numbers in PHP
I don't understand why my code doesn't work.
Here is the instructions about the problem:
Given the triangle of consecutive odd numbers:
             1
          3     5
       7     9    11
   13    15    17    19
21    23    25    27    29
...

Calculate the sum of the numbers in the nth row of this triangle (starting at index 1) e.g.: (Input --> Output)
1 -->  1
2 --> 3 + 5 = 8

Bellow is my code written to the PHP:
function rowSumOddNumbers($n) {
  if ($n==1){
    return 1;
  }
  
  $licznik = 0;
  
  for ($i=$n; $i>0; $i--){
    $licznik += $i;
  }
  
  $liczba = ($licznik*$n) - 1;
  $suma = 0;

  
  for ($i=$n; $i>0; $i--){
    $suma += $liczba;
    $liczba = $liczba - 2;
  }
  
  return $suma;
  
}

The testcase which broke my code was:
Failed asserting that 15210 is identical to 2197.
I don't want to know what code will make this fine, but a clue why mine doesn't work. Please help
I tried to calculate how my code react and it seems fine.

Can you use a debugger to track what your code actually does, and see where that differs from what you expected?

You don't need the loops, there's a simple mathematical solution. The sum in row N is always N cubed: 1, 8, 27, 64, ...

Your algorithm doesn't seem to be at all related to what you're trying to do. Both your loops run $n times. You're never limiting your total to just the numbers on a single row.

You should start with nested loops that figure out the number that row N starts with. Then use a second loop that adds up the N odd numbers on that row.

@Olivier apparently this site will let anyone post anything. I should stay off public sites until my coffee kicks in.

A mathematical solution (I know, not asked, but I couldn't resist):
function rowSumOddNumbers($n) 
{
  # $start is the first value of a row
  $start = $n * ($n-1) + 1;
  return ( $start + $n - 1 ) * $n;
}

You can also combine both calculations. This gives:
function rowSumOddNumbers($n) 
{
  return $n**3;
}

